# Passing form to partial with remote true update - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5.2.2. I have a form with `remote: true`. I have a partial that displays shipping methods where I render nested shipping methods available for a quote. My form accepts nested attributes also.

My form works fine, but on update I am wanting to render the updated shipping methods if they have changed but since I pass the original form to my partial, I don't have that variable available on update. Here is my partial

_shipping_rates.html.erb

```
<h2> Shipping Rates</h2>
<div id="quote-shipping-rates">
    <%= form.collection_radio_buttons(:shipping_method_id, quote.shipping_methods.sort_by(&:price), :id, :name, { checked: quote.shipping_method_id }) do |b| %>
    <%= b.radio_button %>
    <%= b.label %>
    (<span class="text-red"><%= number_to_currency(b.object.price) %></span>)
    <br />
<% end %>
```

On the initial page load I call the partial like this:

```
<%= render 'shipping_methods', :form => u , :quote => @quote %>
```

On update, I have the following file that executes JavaScript to update the DOM.

update.js.erb

I want to do something like this but I wasn't sure if there was some Rails way to recreate the form variable and pass it to the partial.

```
$("#quote-shipping-rates").html("");
$("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "shipping_methods", :form => u , :quote => @quote) %>").appendTo("#quote-shipping-rates");
```